# Getting error in azure notebooks while deploying : ImportError: No module named azure.storage.blob

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

We are usign azure ml stodio workspace and trying to deploy model using azure notebooks present in ml studio.

Imported azure-storage using below code.

```
!pip install azure-storage==0.36.0
```

Its working when i run locally but when its deployed to ML studio workspace, its giving us this error:

{u'error': {u'message': u'Module execution encountered an error.', u'code': u'ModuleExecutionError', u'details': [{u'message': u'Error 0085: The following error occurred during script evaluation, please view the output log for more information:\r\n---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ----------\r\nCaught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):\n File "\server\InvokePy.py", line 120, in executeScript\n outframe = mod.azureml_main(*inframes)\n File "\temp\1450604638.py", line 1094, in azureml_main\n results.append(__user_function(client_code))\n File "", line 17, in final_model\n File "", line 5, in data_input\nImportError: No module named azure.storage.blob\n\r\n\r\n---------- End of error message from Python interpreter ----------', u'code': u'85', u'target': u'Execute Python Script RRS'}]}}

Code used to deploy:

```
from azureml import Workspace
ws = Workspace()
workspace_id = 'xxxxx'
authorization_token = 'yyyyyy'

from azureml import services
@services.publish(workspace_id, authorization_token)
@services.types(client_code = int)
@services.returns(int)

def final_model(client_code):
import pandas as pd
data_input(account_name,key) # this function has code related to importing data from blob
return client_code

service_url = final_model.service.url
api_key = final_model.service.api_key
help_url = final_model.service.help_url
service_id = final_model.service.service_id
```

What is the package name which is present in ML studio workspace to import data from blob so that it runs when its deployed there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading through installing dependencies in this [**documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/execute-python-script)

Running the bellow command may resolve the dependencies/missing modules, however, This package is not compatible with azure-storage. If you installed azure-storage, or if you installed azure 1.x/2.x and didn’t uninstall azure-storage, you must uninstall azure-storage first

```
pip install azure
```

More details on the above command can be found [**here**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure)